# Getting AJAX load more to work with custom Wordpress related posts Query?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I"m using the tutorial from this blog post to implement Ajax Load More functionality. https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/load-more-posts-ajax.html

I've successfully implemented this on my archive page for all blog posts. However, I've got several "RElated Posts" sections that use custom WP Queries that I can't get to work. I've tried the solution in this comment: https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/load-more-posts-ajax.html#comment-1055

It loads new posts, but they are not adhering to the argumenets of the custom query (specifically displaying posts only in the same category).

The custom query is working (it displays 4 related posts from the same category). When i'm loading more, it is not respecting pagination (it's loading 6 posts instead of 4) and it is not respecting the query (it is loading posts not in the same category).

```
<div class="related-blog-posts gray-bg pt-5 pb-5 blog">
  <div class="related-title pb-3">
        <h1 class="mb-2">Related Stories</h1>
        <img src="/dcustom/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Path-137@2x.png" />
      </div><!-- scroll-down-->    

      <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

        <?php

        $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

              $query_args = array(

                'category__in'   => wp_get_post_categories( $post->ID ),
                'paged' => $paged,
                'post_type' => 'post', 
                 'posts_per_page' => 4,
                 'post__not_in'   => array( $post->ID ),
                     'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'DESC'
              );

        $third_query = new WP_Query( $query_args ); ?>


  <?php

//Loop through posts and display...
    if($third_query->have_posts()) : ?>
     <?php while ($third_query->have_posts() ) : $third_query->the_post(); ?>

                <?php get_template_part('template-parts/content-related-blog-posts'); ?>

      <?php endwhile; ?><!-- end the loop-->
<?php endif; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

 <?php // don't display the button if there are not enough posts
if (  $third_query->max_num_pages > 1 )
  echo '<a class="custom_loadmore btn btn-primary">More posts</a>'; // you can use <a> as well
?>

<?php endif; ?><!-- end loop if--->
              </div><!-- row -->

            </div><!-- container -->
</div><!-- related-case-studies-->


  <script>
    var test = '<?php echo serialize( $third_query->query_vars ) ?>',
    current_page_myajax = 1,
    max_page_myajax = <?php echo $third_query->max_num_pages ?>
</script>
<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/js/myloadmore.js"></script>
```

```
jQuery(function($){ // use jQuery code inside this to avoid "$ is not defined" error
    $('.misha_loadmore').click(function(){

        var button = $(this),
            data = {
            'action': 'loadmore',
            'query': misha_loadmore_params.posts, // that's how we get params from wp_localize_script() function
            'page' : misha_loadmore_params.current_page
        };

        $.ajax({ // you can also use $.post here
            url : misha_loadmore_params.ajaxurl, // AJAX handler
            data : data,
            type : 'POST',
            beforeSend : function ( xhr ) {
                button.text('Loading...'); // change the button text, you can also add a preloader image
            },
            success : function( data ){
                if( data ) { 
                    button.text( 'More posts' ).prev().after(data); // insert new posts
                    misha_loadmore_params.current_page++;

                    if ( misha_loadmore_params.current_page == misha_loadmore_params.max_page ) 
                        button.remove(); // if last page, remove the button

                    // you can also fire the "post-load" event here if you use a plugin that requires it
                    // $( document.body ).trigger( 'post-load' );
                } else {
                    button.remove(); // if no data, remove the button as well
                }
            }
        });
    });



$('.custom_loadmore').click(function(){
        //custom query on front-page.php
        var button = $(this),
            data = {
            'action': 'loadmore',
            'query': test,
            'page' : current_page_myajax
        };

        $.ajax({
            url : '/dcustom/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', // AJAX handler
            data : data,
            type : 'POST',
            beforeSend : function ( xhr ) {
                button.text('Loading...'); // change the button text, you can also add a preloader image
            },
            success : function( data ){
                if( data ) { 
                    button.text( 'More posts' ).prev().after(data); // insert new posts
                    current_page_myajax++;

                    if ( current_page_myajax == max_page_myajax )
                        button.remove(); // if last page, remove the button
                } else {
                    //button.remove(); // if no data, remove the button as well
                }
            }
        });
    }); 

    });
```

```
function misha_my_load_more_scripts() {

        global $wp_query; 

    // In most cases it is already included on the page and this line can be removed
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

    // register our main script but do not enqueue it yet
    wp_register_script( 'my_loadmore', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/myloadmore.js', array('jquery') );

    // now the most interesting part
    // we have to pass parameters to myloadmore.js script but we can get the parameters values only in PHP
    // you can define variables directly in your HTML but I decided that the most proper way is wp_localize_script()
    wp_localize_script( 'my_loadmore', 'misha_loadmore_params', array(
        'ajaxurl' => site_url() . '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', // WordPress AJAX
        'posts' => json_encode( $wp_query->query_vars ), // everything about your loop is here
        'current_page' => get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
        'max_page' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
    ) );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_loadmore' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'misha_my_load_more_scripts' );


/* AJAX LOOP FOR THE ARCHIVE PAGE */
function misha_loadmore_ajax_handler(){

    // prepare our arguments for the query
    $args = json_decode( stripslashes( $_POST['query'] ), true );
    $args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1; // we need next page to be loaded
    $args['post_status'] = 'publish';

    // it is always better to use WP_Query but not here
    query_posts( $args );

    if( have_posts() ) :

        // run the loop
        while( have_posts() ): the_post();

            // look into your theme code how the posts are inserted, but you can use your own HTML of course
            // do you remember? - my example is adapted for Twenty Seventeen theme

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-index', get_post_format() );

            // for the test purposes comment the line above and uncomment the below one
            // the_title();

        endwhile;

    endif;
    die; // here we exit the script and even no wp_reset_query() required!
}



add_action('wp_ajax_loadmore', 'misha_loadmore_ajax_handler'); // wp_ajax_{action}
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore', 'misha_loadmore_ajax_handler'); // wp_ajax_nopriv_{action}
```

Comment: Not really an answer but a possible solution to your problem: [ajax load more plugin](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/) I use this all the time, it works perfectly.